# 飛んだページ先のJSONをテーブル変換する方法

Tags: json, api, eclipse

失礼します。
EclipseやAPIを利用してWEBアプリを作成しています。
URLに記載されたページに飛ぶとJSON形式のデータが表示されるのですが、可視化しやすいようにテーブルにすることはできないでしょうか？できればURLは固定でなくするのでなく、検索向けのURLにしたいです。
JSONの書式は以下になります。

```
[
    {
        "version": "1.5",
        "codename": "Cupcake"
    },
    {
        "version": "1.6",
        "codename": "Donut"
    },
```

最終的に検索したページに飛びテーブル表示にしたいです。
何卒宜しくお願いします。

Comment: このままですと、情報不足で回答が得られにくいと思います。作成に使っている言語・フレームワーク（Ruby on Rails、Node.js、Python Djangoなど）は何でしょうか。JSONを返すのは、あなたが作成中のWebアプリケーションですか？ それとも外部のWebサービスか何かでしょうか？ あなたが作成中のWebアプリケーションでJSONを返すようにしているならば、質問にそこのソースから抜粋して記載できますか？

Comment: http://hakuhin.jp/js/json.html この辺りを読むと良いと思います。